# ULA just launched a very asymmetric Atlas V 511. Why does its plume look so asymmetric... after SRB jettison?

Tags: atlas-v, plume, rd-180

I've never noticed this before, so I'm asking. Shortly after SRB ejection, the RD-180 plume appears to be very asymmetric. Why is this? If I recall correctly, these are full-flow & there isn't any gas generator exhaust, so I was confused.

Is this "bulge" in the plane between the two nozzles & thus representing a higher-pressure region between the two plumes? Is there some other reason?[image]

[Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNkCmDBDVzU)

Comment: Wow. Gut feel, something is venting, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: that was my inclination after I mentally ruled out gas generator. thought it odd that it would have been venting directly onto the mounted SRB

Comment: I was able to find that the hydraulic system uses kerosene as its fluid; I wonder if it's an open-loop system? So far haven't found any details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the engine configurations for the [Atlas V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_V):

[image: Atlas V engine configs]
Credit: ULA, from [Spaceflight Now article](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/02/11/ula-to-debut-unflown-variant-of-atlas-5-rocket-later-this-year/)

I think it's likely a plume impingement effect from the two nozzles of the RD-180 engine. The plume expands out from each nozzle and between them has nowhere to go but out sideways, I suspect there is a nearly identical one on the other side of the rocket.

This is seen in other Atlas V launches, for example [the Lucy launch (401 config)](https://youtu.be/IThrIVLmvTo?t=79), [SBIRS GEO May 2021 (421 config)](https://youtu.be/xmkjlLWDpq4?t=104), [NROL-101 (531 config)](https://youtu.be/XSJlLS2Mjxo?t=109) to show a few.